# NPM: run build in parallel, but wait for any errors

Tags: javascript, npm, build

I have a few Angular projects that will start to build
via one npm command, like

```
npm run build:project1 & npm run build:project2
```

The problem is: if one of them fails - the terminal doesn't show me an error.

How can I run them in parallel, but get an error if either of the scripts failed?

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently to do this